# JavaScript: Make global variables and functions unique

Tags: javascript

I started to a project long time ago. It became huge by the time so I divided into modules. I designed different js files for each but now I realized that I've used dublicate globals. Is there any tool to scan my scripts and alert for dublicates?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and don't use lots of globals. Use a single global that references an object, and put your values there. Much easier to test that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan? Not really, that I know of.

The nice solution to this problem is to use namespaces and closures to hide the variables, and minimise the reliance on globals.

```
quuxModule = (function() {
  var foovar = 3;
  var barvar = 5;
  function foo() {
    return foovar;
  }
  function bar() {
    return barvar;
  }
  return {
    bar: bar,
    barvar: barvar
  }
})();

quuxModule.barvar; // 5
quuxModule.foovar; // undefined
quuxModule.bar(); // 5
quuxModule.foo(); // foo is private, undefined() raises TypeError
```

Or you could go a step further and use RequireJS to make proper modules.

Comment: RequireJS seems to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good practice but yeah, you can.
just put it on top before importing the js files.

```
<script>
// your global variable
var yourGlobalvariable;
</script>

//import scripts
<script src="yourscript1.js"></script>
<script src="yourscript2.js"></script>
```